# Doctrine 2.3.6 with Slim Framework : where to create doctrine_cli.php

Tags: php, doctrine, slim

I am currently trying to set up Doctrine with my Slim application.

I read this guide : http://busypeoples.github.io/post/slim-doctrine/.
Everything is fine until i hit the **Adding the Doctrine Commandline Tool** part.

It explains that I need a **doctrine_cli.php** file in order to set up the command line tool, with this code inside :

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$em = //Some code to create EntityManager

$helpers = new Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));
```

Where should I create  **doctrine_cli.php** ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer some minutes ago. It may help someone in the future.

It appears that you can put the config file **anywhere**, as long as you execute the command line in the **same directory**.

---

### Explanation :

You call the commandline tool this way (*see [Doctrine Documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#setting-up-the-commandline-tool) for reference*) :

```
$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

This calls a bash script in `vendor/bin/`, wich calls `doctrine.php` in `vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/`.
In this file you can see this line :

```
$configFile = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cli-config.php';
```

This means that :

- The config file used by Doctrine implementation is named `cli-config.php`, and not `doctrine_cli.php`.
- Doctrine search the file with `getcwd()`, wich refers to the directory you are into when you execute the command line.

---

### In short :

1. Create a **cli-config.php** file in `any/path/you/want` (*see [Doctrine Documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#setting-up-the-commandline-tool) for reference*).

   ```
   <?php
   require 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
   $em = //Some code to create EntityManager
   $helpers = new Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
       'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
       'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
   ));
   ```
2. Execute your command line tool **in the same directory**

   ```
   $ cd any/path/you/want
   any/path/you/want$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
   ```

**Edit :**
For Doctrine 2.4, you can also put it in a directory named `config` and execute the command line tool in `config` parent directory